# Best practice for using derived class in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a Base class:

```
class Base{
public:
    int id;
    virtual void method();
    bool identify(int _id);
...
}
```

and some derived classes:

```
class d1:public Base{
public:
    int id;
    void method();
    bool identify(int _id);
...
}

class d2:public Base{
public:
    int id;
    void method();
    bool identify(int _id);
...
}
```

Every sub class do different jobs from one another in it's method,according to it's id,the method identify() will check whether this sub class will have to handle the data or not.

Now,I have an array that stores all the instance of sub classes,like:
Base *instances[];

When data comes,I did:

```
for(i=0;i<instances.length;i++){
    Base *temp=instances[i];
    if(temp->identify(id))
        temp->method(data);
}
```

However,I got the job done.But just don't feel comfortable with this approach.

So,my question is: **what is the best practice for this ?**

ps:I know the concept of polymorphism,but just don't know how to use it.I'm new to c++,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _'But just don't feel comfortable ...'_ What exactly makes you uncomfortable?

Comment: Shouldn't `identify` be virtual? If so, please fix this first, then we can think of a better answer :)

Comment: `method()` doesn't have an argument, but in the for loop, you pass one..

Comment: It isn't clear which problem you are trying to solve. Just make `method` do something resonable whenever it is called, and call it always.

Comment: btw, since you explictly asked for it: the best approach is to restrict virtual functions (except of the destructor) to private, and to make all public functions non-virtual. The non-virtual public functions should then call the virtual private ones. Perhaps this idiom can be applied quite naturally to your problem.

Comment: If you have any virtual functions, consider making the destructor virtual too so you may delete using a pointer to derived... @ChristianHackl: That's debatable, and I for one don't hold with that. This question is quite likely to devolve into a style-war.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ,before I handle any data,the instances are already been created there,some of them may be used while some of them may not,this makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to decide in the calling code whether to call a method of the class or not based on it's virtual type, you are not using polymorphism in a good way. Polymorphism is about making the implementing classes behave different from one another, even though they are used like an instance of their base class. So, your code should have looked like this:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void method(int id, /*args*/) { }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void method(int id, /*args*/) override {
            if(id == something) {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void method(int id, /*args*/) override {
            if(id == somethingElse) {
                //Do other stuff
            }
        }
};
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<instances.length;i++) {
    instances[i]->method(data);
}
```

This using code is completely ignorant of what kind of object it call `method()` on, all it should need to know is that it is calling `method()` on some implementation of `Base`.

Comment: Thank you cmaster,for your explanation to polymorphism. Your code will do the job another way ,due to my understanding, but I still have to new the correct sub class when the data comes,right ? Maybe I  have to write a factory class that handles the logic between data and class ,after that all I have to do is just throw the data to the factory class and wait for feedback .

Comment: Yes, you need to know the precise class when you do `new`. However, you can encapsulate the `new` into any function that has ready access to the information needed to make the subclass decision. This may be the client code, it may be another class that manages that information, it may be a dedicated factory class, or it may be a simple factory function within the base class itself. There are many options, which one is best depends entirely on the context.

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying those things for me, maybe there's no perfect way to do this,unless I fully acquire the skills in c++.